# Fill forward a DataFrame with matching values

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame of booleans. I would like to replace the 2 `False` values that are directly positioned after a `True` value. I thought the [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method would do it since the 5th example seems to be what I am looking for.

Here is what I do:

```
dataIn = pd.DataFrame([False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False])
dataOut = dataIn.replace(to_replace=False, method='ffill', limit=2)
>>> TypeError: No matching signature found
```

Here is the output I am looking for:

```
dataOut = pd.DataFrame([False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False])
```

Comment: 1) Do not use keywords (`input`) as your variable. 2) is your input a dataframe or a series?

Comment: 1) Changed the variable name. 2) for the example it could be a Series, but my case is a DataFarme of several columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for both answers above. But actually, it seems the `.replace()` can be used, but it does not entirely handle booleans. 
By replacing them temporarily by `int`, it is possible to use it:

```
dataIn = pd.DataFrame([False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False])
dataOut = dataIn.astype(int).replace(to_replace=False, method='ffill', limit=2).astype(bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# create a series not a dateframe
# if you have a dataframe then assign to a new variable as a series
# s = df['bool_col']

s = pd.Series([False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False])
# create a mask based on the logic using shift
mask = (s == False) & (((s.shift(1) == True) & (s.shift(-1) == False))\
                       | ((s.shift(2) == True) & (s.shift(1) == False)))
# numpy.where to create the new output
np.where(mask, True, s)

# array([False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False])

# assign to a new column in the frame (if you want)
# df['new_col'] = np.where(mask, True, s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function which conditionally replaces 2 first elements with *True*:

```
def condRepl(grp):
    rv = grp.copy()
    if grp.size >= 2 and grp.eq(False).all():
        rv.iloc[0:2] = [True] * 2
    return rv
```

The condition triggering this replace is:

- group has 2 elements or more,
- the group is composed solely of *False* values.

Then, using this function, transform each group of "new" values
(each change in the value starts a new group):

```
dataIn[0] = dataIn[0].groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).transform(condRepl)
```